# Nginx config to redirect myserver.com to Tableau tabserver.com on login and logout

Tags: reactjs, nginx, tableau-api, business-intelligence, tableau-desktop

I want to redirect a user from my webapp(myserver.com) to Tableau server hosted at tabserver.com

Whenever I hit the login URL in the browser for tabserver.com the URL bar shows this: tabserver.com/signin or tabserver.com/signin?redirect=someURL

Similarly, when I logout from tableau server, the URL bar always show this:tabserver.com/signin?disableAutoSignin=yes

So login and logout URLs both point to /signin with change in URL parameters.

Can the nginx config be configured so that:

1. By hitting tabserver.com/#/site/, it redirects me to myserver.com?
2. And when logging out, it also redirects me to myserver.com?

Answer (score 1):

```
If you are using NGINX’s main configuration file nginx.conf 
without virtual hosts.

Sudo vi /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

(Sudo is for Linux systems)

configure separate virtual hosts for your website (e.g www.myweb.com), such as /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myweb.conf
```

then open it with the following command.

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mysite.conf

(Use Sudo is for Linux systems)

For example if you want to redirect /login to new domain
([www.myserver.com](http://www.myserver.com)), then add the following location block
inside your server block.

```
server{
    location /login {
    rewrite ^/login(.*)$ https://www.myserver.com/$1 redirect;
    }
}

rewrite – rewrite command tells NGINX to change one or more 
URLs that match a given pattern (e.g /login) to another URL.

^/login – URL paths that start with /login. You can change it to 
 another URL as you need it.

(.*) – match one or more characters. In our case, it means 
anything that follows /login.

$ – end of string

 $1 - URL part after /login
```

Comment: Okay. Will nginx work to match exact URLs. Because I can have the following scenario: 1. /login redirects to myserver 2. /logout redirects to myserver But when i push data to tableau server it calls /login/someURL. So will this API call to push data will not be affected by rules 1. and 2?